# Unable to use Google geocoding api in react native app

Tags: react-native, geocoding, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to implement google's geocoding for reverse geocoding in my react native app, i wanted to apply restrictions in google console for iOS app with bundle id's. But when i apply restrictions i'm always getting ACCESS_DENIED response with google geocoding api url.

I have enabled the geocoding api and Maps Javascript API, and also the billing set up is done, but still i'm getting same response.

How do i implement reverse geocoding in my app with restrictions enabled for iOS.

Any Answers/Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried filing a support case? It appears that you need your account/project to be inspected. If you have not done so, I suggest that you do in the Google Cloud Console to open a personalized communication channel: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case

Comment: I have read in this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822639 that Application restrictions doesn't work for iOS or android if we are using Geocoding api. Bundle level restrictions works only with SDK i.e Google Maps SDK iOS and Android. Only the geocoding web api's(Url's) can only be restricted with IP Address if we use HTTP from mobile app using react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Geocoding API, app restrictions don't work on iOS or Android. Only the Google Maps SDK can use bundle restrictions. With React Native, if you're using web APIs, you can only restrict by IP address.